# Erro no PHP no editor Atom

Tags: php, atom

estou experimentando o editor Atom por indicações, instalei os pacotes essenciais mas está dando erro quando digito códigos PHP. O que posso fazer para resolver esse problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu nunca consegui usar o Atom, era pesado e dava erros, agora eu uso netbeans é pesado, mas funciona

Comment: Instale o pacote `atom-autocomplete-php` você provavelmente instalou o package `autocomplete-php`  sem o atom na frente

Comment: Outra coisa, você instalou o `php`? Qual você está usando?

Answer (score 0):

Isso significa que as variáveis de ambiente não tem o caminho do php, para adicionar primeiro localize a pasta aonde se encontra o PHP, supondo que seja `c:\php\php.exe` copie somente o `c:\php`, agora faça o seguinte

- Clique com o direito do mouse/rato no <kbd>Meu Computador</kbd> e <kbd>Propriedades</kbd>
- No menu lateral esquerdo clique no <kbd>Configurações avançadas do sistema</kbd>
- Procure um botão chamado <kbd>Variáveis de ambiente</kbd>, clique nele
- Procure a variável *PATH* e clique duas vezes, deve retornar algo semelhante a isto:

  > C:\Users\Inphinit\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\binC:\Users\Inphinit\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Inphinit\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\cmd;C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin

Então no final adicione `;C:\php;`, assim:

> C:\Users\Inphinit\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\binC:\Users\Inphinit\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Inphinit\AppData\Local\GitHub\PortableGit_f02737a78695063deace08e96d5042710d3e32db\cmd;C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin;**C:\php;**

Aperte em Ok em ambas janelas, até fechar tudo, então faça logoff no Windows e o logon em seguida, o PHP estará disponível globalmente.

Comment: Como devo fazer no ubuntu?

Comment: Caro @Tiago depende de como você instalou o PHP, porque se instalou via APT-GET deveria ficar disponivel na linha de comando ($PATH) sozinho, o proprio APT faz isso, agora se instalou Xampp ou algum outro ai é diferente, poderia dizer o que usa ai? Faça assim, vá no terminal e digita apenas `php -v` e me diga se ele informou a versão do PHP, se tiver informado é porque o PHP esta ok